# Loop through the labels of a page to assign text

Tags: asp.net, text, loops, label

I have some 20 labels on my aspx page for which the IDs are lbl1,lbl2....lbl20 and  text is driven by SqlServer table. Is there any easy way to loop through all the labels on the page and assing the text from reader.
I did some thing like but it doesn't work.

```
SqlDataReader Reader = new SqlDataReader();

        int i = 0;
         while(Reader.read())
         {
             label lbl = new label();

             lbl.ID = "label" + i;
             lbl.text = Reader["ColumnName"].ToString();


         }
```

Is there any other method through which I can loop through all the labels and assign text for it?

Comment: You forgot to increment the counter: i++

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is use the findcontrol method.  This would work well because all your labels are named with a "lbl0", "lbl1"... convention.

**start looping:

```
int index = 0;

string currentLabel = "lbl" + index.ToString();

index++;

Control myControl1 = FindControl(currentLabel);

// cast control to type: (label)

// apply text from reader**
```

Give that a shot.  Hope it works out

Comment: It looks like it should work for me. Let me give it a shot and will update on how it went through. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have them in a container, i think you can do something like this below:

```
For Each lbl As Control In Grid1.Children
  If TypeOf lbl Is Label Then
    'your logic
  End If
Next
```

I have only tried this in silverlight however, so i'm not sure it works, or if putting them all in a container is practical in your case.

Comment: Putting them in container is not practical in my case. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past and I just tested it out.

You can do this because every page has a form

```
HtmlForm form1 = (HtmlForm)Page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    ((TextBox)form1.FindControl("label" + i)).Text = "This is label number " + i;
}
```

If you have a master page change the first line to this

```
ContentPlaceHolder ph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
```